# Pymongo - update recordset after find query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have following Mongo data structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5fe71691afebd0409cb6d97d'),
    video_path: '/media/test.mp4',
    api_processed: false,
    samples: [
        {
            frame: 1,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'
        },
        {
            frame: 2,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'
        }
            ],
    TOT_execution_time: '0:00:10.019675'
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('5fe0d8e8ce78fe286b634908'),
    video_path: '/media/test2.mp4',
    api_processed: false,
    samples: [
        {
            frame: 1,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'
        },
        {
            frame: 2,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'
        }
            ],
    TOT_execution_time: '0:00:16.019675'
}
```

My goal is to update the record with filter "api_processed: false", adding a new Key-value, after performing some processing.

I have made this query:

```
mydoc = mycol.find( { "api_processed": False},
{ "_id": 1,"samples.sample": 1}
)
```

My goal is to iterate over results and insert a new key-value in the corresponding sample:

```
for x in mydoc:
  for sample in x.get('samples', []):
    doc = mycol.update_one(
                              {"_id" : x['_id']},
                              {
                              "$push": { "samples": { "api_response": "0" }
                              }
                              }
                              )
```

If I use above code, it does not correcly iterate to the correct sample and it produce this wrong results (NOTE: api_response should be nested on each sample):

```
   {
        _id: ObjectId('5fe71691afebd0409cb6d97d'),
        video_path: '/media/test.mp4',
        api_processed: true,
        samples: [
            {
                frame: 1,
                sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            },
            {
                frame: 2,
                sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            }
                ],
        TOT_execution_time: '0:00:10.019675',
        api_response : '0',
        api_response : '0'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('5fe0d8e8ce78fe286b634908'),
        video_path: '/media/test2.mp4',
        api_processed: true,
        samples: [
            {
                frame: 1,
                sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            },
            {
                frame: 2,
                sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            }
                ],
        TOT_execution_time: '0:00:16.019675',
        api_response : '1',
        api_response : '1'
    }
```

What I would like to obtain I'll be something like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5fe71691afebd0409cb6d97d'),
    video_path: '/media/test.mp4',
    api_processed: true,
    samples: [
        {
            frame: 1,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            api_response : '0'
        },
        {
            frame: 2,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            api_response : '0'
        }
            ],
    TOT_execution_time: '0:00:10.019675'
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('5fe0d8e8ce78fe286b634908'),
    video_path: '/media/test2.mp4',
    api_processed: true,
    samples: [
        {
            frame: 1,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            api_response : '1'
        },
        {
            frame: 2,
            sample: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD',
            api_response : '1'
        }
            ],
    TOT_execution_time: '0:00:16.019675'
}
```

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Add the actual result and define all variables in your code (replace response.text with a sample text string).

Comment: I just updated it: response.text is a simple boolean var.my problem is that I still not get how to put the "api_response" in the nested sample structure. thx.

Answer (score 0):

you can use similar to,

```
self.db["db_name"].update(
            {"_id": ObjectId(some_id)},
            {"$set": {
                "status": "success",
                "column_name": "something"
                }}
            )
```

Comment: Using "SET" prev key under "sample" will be overwritten